# datetime.strptime () throws 'does not match format' error

Tags: python, django

I get

```
time data '19/Apr/2011:22:12:39' does not match format '%d/%b/%y:%H:%M:%S'
```

when using `datetime.strptime('19/Apr/2011:22:12:39','%d/%b/%y:%H:%M:%S')`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try `%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S` instead - `%y` right now means 11.

You can "debug" datetime formats easily using `date` (on the shell and not on python, I mean, assuming you're running GNU/Linux or similar):

```
date '+%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S'
05/May/2011:09:00:41
```

Comment: Or you can use time.strftime() to do the same thing as that 'date' command, without requiring the 'date' command :)

Answer (score 12):

You're checking for a 2 digit year ( %y ) instead of a four digit ( %Y )

Answer (score 6):

You want %Y instead of %y. %Y means you want the century, %y is no century and the year is displayed from 00 to 99.