# Python - Convert string to date

Tags: python, datetime

Hi I have an input string "25-11-12" which needs to be converted to date time format. I have tried below

datetime.strptime(string1,%d-%m-%Y) but since the input year is just '12' i am unable to proceed with error that time data doesnot match the format. Can someone please help with conversion. Thanks!

Comment: A google search would have solved your issue. A possible answer to your question was https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5897263/datetime-strptime-throws-does-not-match-format-error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior):

> %y    Year without century as a zero-padded decimal number.   00, 01, …, 99
>   %Y    Year with century as a decimal number.  1970, 1988, 2001, 2013

So, I suppose the answer is:

```
datetime.strptime(string1,'%d-%m-%y')
```